React Router BrowserRouter Returns 404 After Build but Works in Development
I am building a React application using react-router-dom with createBrowserRouter. The app works fine in development mode, but after building and deploying, direct URL access like website.com/test returns a 404 Not Found. However, the page works properly at website.com/#/test.
Here is the routing code I'm using:
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import Test from "./Test";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "/test",
    element: <Test />,
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </StrictMode>
);

Additional Info:
I'm using static hosting (e.g., Netlify/Vercel).
I'd prefer to stick with BrowserRouter or createBrowserRouter.
In development mode (npm run dev), all pages load perfectly, including website.com/test. However, once I run a production build and deploy (npm run build), direct access to any URL like website.com/test gives a 404, unless I switch to the hash-based URL (website.com/#/test).
What do I need to do to make the routes work properly in production without using HashRouter?
I have uploaded the example website to blog.aogung.com

If "website.com/#/test" is working then that sure looks like you have built and deployed a version of your app using the HashRouter. When you use a BrowserRouter have you correctly re-built and re-deployed the new build? Do you know if the server environment you are hosting from supports non-hash routing? Where are you deploying/hosting your app? If Netlify/Vercel then check these deployment docs. Please [edit] to provide more context and relevant details.

@DrewReese Yes, the example website blog.aogung.com is using BrowserRouter but still I have to  visit /#/test for it to work

"https://blog.aogung.com/#/test" loads the same page as just "https://blog.aogung.com/" for me, but "https://blog.aogung.com/test" returns a 404. If you are using a BrowserRouter then the server is likely just ignoring the hash with regards to what page to send back to the client. The server should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app.
